# mongoTemplate: custom converter with non standard objects

Tags: spring, mongodb

I found an issue when using a custom converter.

Let's say my to objects are:

```
public class Foo {
    private String id;
    private Bar bar;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Bar getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}

public class Bar {
    private String id;
    private String property;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public void setProperty(String property) {
        this.property = property;
    }
}
```

If they are inserted into the MongoDB, everything works fine, as long as no custom converter is involved.

```
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    bar.setProperty("Test");
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.setBar(bar);

    mongoTemplate.insert(bar);
    mongoTemplate.insert(foo);
```

Results:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "$oid" : "51a346059f2c9d656019798e"
    },
    "_class" : "Bar",
    "property" : "Test"
}
{
    "_id" : {
        "$oid" : "51a346059f2c9d656019798f"
    },
    "_class" : "Foo",
    "bar" : {
        "_id" : {
            "$oid" : "51a346059f2c9d656019798e"
        },
        "property" : "Test"
    }
}
```

Now I wrote a custom converter, cause Foo needs to be stored in a special way.

```
public class FooWriteConverter implements Converter<Foo, DBObject> {

    @Override
    public DBObject convert(Foo source) {
        DBObject dbo = new BasicDBObject();
        dbo.put("id", source.getId());
        dbo.put("bar", source.getBar());
        return dbo;
    }

}
```

Now I get this error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't serialize class Bar
```

So, it looks like I can't fall back to the default conversion for properties of an object, that is converted using a custom converter?!

Any useful solutions instead of doing all conversion manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use default conversion for properties in custom converter you need a MongoConverter class help.

```
public class FooWriteConverter implements Converter<Foo, DBObject> {
    private MongoConverter mongoConverter;

    public FooWriteConverter(MongoConverter mongoConverter) {
        this.mongoConverter = mongoConverter;
    }

    @Override
    public DBObject convert(Foo source) {
        DBObject dbo = new BasicDBObject();
        dbo.put("id", source.getId());

        DBObject bar = new BasicDBObject();
        mongoConverter.write(source.getBar(), bar);
        dbo.put("bar", bar);
        return dbo;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works fine. How do I implement the way back? mongoConverter.read(Bar.class... does not work, it says the method read(Class<R> ... is not applicable for the arguments Class<Bar>

Comment: I withdraw the question, don't know what was wrong but it works using read.